# MongoDB Several coordinates do not work with geonear

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb and I have a problem with geoNear. Some latitude and longitude points do not work, and mainly the default ones on the xcode simulator. With my phone everything works perfectly, any idea?  Error:

> Failed to determine whether query system can provide a covered
>   projection :: caused by :: geo near accepts just one argument when
>   querying for a GeoJSON point. Extra field found: $minDistance: 15000.0

Work with [ 40.7648, -73.9808 ] but not work with [ 37.33233141, -122.0312186 ]. Why ?

```
return this.aggregate([
        {
            $geoNear: {
                near: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: coordinates
                },

                maxDistance: maxDistance ? maxDistance * 1000 : 100 * 1000,
                minDistance: minDistance ? minDistance * 1000 : 0,
                distanceField: "distance",
                spherical: false

            }
        },
        {
            $group:
            {
                _id: "$city",
                events: { $push: { id: '$_id', title: "$name", type: '$type', city: '$city', distance: '$distance', time: '$about.time', date: '$about.date', address: '$about.address', price: '$about.price', coordinates: '$location.coordinates' } }
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: { "events.distance":1 }
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Legacy coordinates should be `[ longitude, latitude ]`.  `-122` is not a valid latitude.  That error message is quite misleading.

Comment: Ah okay thank you ! I understood my mistake